# Joining two datasets by (non-uniform) names

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, fuzzyjoin

I need to join two datasets and the only identifier in both are the company names. For example:

```
db1 <- tibble(
  Company = c('Bombardier Inc.','Honeywell Development Corp','The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), Ulc (“Pbgc”)','PepsiCo Canada ULC'),
  var1 = 1:4
)

db2 <- tibble(
  Name = c('Bombardier Inc.','Honeywell Dev Corp','The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), ULC','PepsiCo Canada ULC (“Pcu”)'),
  var2 = 6:9
)
```

Obviously a straightforward `dplyr::left_join()` is not going to work. I tried the following which didn't work:

```
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(db1,db2,by=c('Company'='Name'))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Company                                          var1 Name             var2
  <chr>                                           <int> <chr>           <int>
1 Bombardier Inc.                                     1 Bombardier Inc.     6
2 Honeywell Development Corp                          2 NA                 NA
3 The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), Ulc (“Pbgc”)     3 NA                 NA
4 PepsiCo Canada ULC                                  4 NA                 NA
```

I made some progress by removing "nonessential" characters from the names:

```
db1 <- db1 %>% mutate(Company.alt = str_remove_all(Company,regex(
  'The|Canada|Inc|Ltd|Company|\\bCo\\b|Corporation|Corp|Group|ULC|[:punct:]',
  ignore_case = T
)) %>% str_squish())

db2 <- db2 %>% mutate(Name.alt = str_remove_all(Name,regex(
  'The|Canada|Inc|Ltd|Company|\\bCo\\b|Corporation|Corp|Group|ULC|[:punct:]',
  ignore_case = T
)) %>% str_squish())

fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(db1,db2,by=c('Company.alt'='Name.alt'))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  Company                                          var1 Company.alt           Name            var2 Name.alt 
  <chr>                                           <int> <chr>                 <chr>          <int> <chr>    
1 Bombardier Inc.                                     1 Bombardier            Bombardier In~     6 Bombardi~
2 Honeywell Development Corp                          2 Honeywell Development Honeywell Dev~     7 Honeywel~
3 The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), Ulc (“Pbgc”)     3 Pepsi Bottling Pbgc   The Pepsi Bot~     8 Pepsi Bo~
4 PepsiCo Canada ULC                                  4 PepsiCo               NA                NA NA
```

But this still left the last row unmatched. For greater clarity, the last row of `Company.alt` is `PepsiCo` which is not considered a fuzzy match with `Name.alt`'s last row of `PepsiCo Pcu`.

Is there way to successfully left-join the two datasets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) phonics** The phonics package has numerous methods for approximate matching such as soundex.  See the package documentation for other methods.

```
library(dplyr)
library(phonics)

db1s <- mutate(db1, s = soundex(Company, clean = FALSE))
db2s <- mutate(db2, s = soundex(Name, clean = FALSE))
left_join(db1s, db2s)
```

giving:

```
Joining, by = "s"
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Company                                          var1 s     Name          var2
  <chr>                                           <int> <chr> <chr>        <int>
1 Bombardier Inc.                                     1 B516  Bombardier ~     6
2 Honeywell Development Corp                          2 H543  Honeywell D~     7
3 The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), Ulc (“Pbgc”)     3 T112  The Pepsi B~     8
4 PepsiCo Canada ULC                                  4 P122  PepsiCo Can~     9
```

**2) SQLite**  SQLite has a built-in soundex function.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *
  from db1
  left join db2 on soundex(Company) = soundex(Name)")
```

giving:

```
                                          Company var1                                   Name var2
1                                 Bombardier Inc.    1                        Bombardier Inc.    6
2                      Honeywell Development Corp    2                     Honeywell Dev Corp    7
3 The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), Ulc (“Pbgc”)    3 The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), ULC    8
4                              PepsiCo Canada ULC    4             PepsiCo Canada ULC (“Pcu”)    9
```

Comment: This is cool! Would increasing the `maxCodeLen` improve match precision, or is there an optimal `maxCodeLen` for matching?

Comment: Presumably that is the case.  Practically one would have to use  trial and error with the various phonics algorithms and arguments to find which one(s) work best with your particular dataset.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

We could join `db1` `db2` based on fuzzy string matching of their columns.

With `max_dist` we could define the Maximum distance to use for joining

See: `?stringdist_left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(x=db1, y=db2, max_dist = .35, 
                                by=c('Company'='Name'), 
                                method = 'jaccard', 
                                distance_col = "dist")
```

```
  Company                                          var1 Name                                    var2  dist
  <chr>                                           <int> <chr>                                  <int> <dbl>
1 Bombardier Inc.                                     1 Bombardier Inc.                            6 0    
2 Honeywell Development Corp                          2 Honeywell Dev Corp                         7 0.133
3 The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), Ulc (“Pbgc”)     3 The Pepsi Bottling Group (Canada), ULC     8 0.172
4 PepsiCo Canada ULC                                  4 PepsiCo Canada ULC (“Pcu”)                 9 0.316
```

Comment: Thanks! Would the `max_dist` need to be adjusted depending on the context?

Comment: Yes exactly. This depends on your data. see the help file provided.